# Build only driver file (.sys) without .bsc etc

Tags: c, build, kernel, output, driver

I have a KernelDriver project. Now I would like to build only the .sys file without the .cert .bsc etc.
Can anyone help me?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score -2):

Ok, got it via "BuildEvents" and then CommandLine arguments.